# Monitor Calibration software

Tags: nvidia, multiple-monitors, monitor, colors

I was wondering if there is any software for monitor calibration available for ubuntu? Like the tools they have available for TVs, when you first buy them.

I would especially appreciate answers with one click calibration for color, contrast and brightness. I know these are available on the monitors themselves, but I hate clicking around. Anything specific for users with nvidia cards?

Please and thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What exactly do you mean by *monitor calibration*?  It's impossible to calibrate a monitor with software alone, you need a **color measuring instrument** for that (which is an rather expensive tool).

If you really want to calibrate your monitor, there is [GNOME Color Manager](http://projects.gnome.org/gnome-color-manager/) and the commandline tool ArgyllCMS (the former uses the latter for doing the actual calibration).

```
sudo apt-get install gnome-color-manager argyll
```

GNOME Color Manager shows up in the system configuration as "Color Profiles" (or something similar translated in your language).

Answer (score 1):

`nvidia-settings` may be what you're looking for. In particular the X Server Color Correction section. It's available in the repos